# Unable to exclude two of the same type in a selector

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Okay while trying to make a scroll like thing that summons lightning.. I realized it targeted villagers, how can I fix this command to do that?

```
/execute @e[r=8,type=!Player,type=!Villager,count=-1] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for 1.13+: This now just works. `type=!player,type=!villager` works exactly as expected.

---

Old answer for 1.12: You cannot have more than one parameter with the same key name. The last one defined will be used instead.

To exclude two different entities based on `type`, you can assign a label separately and then target those that do not have the label.

As well, the correct parameter for maximum count is `c`, **not** `count`.

Example using a scoreboard team:

```
/scoreboard teams add Exclude

/scoreboard teams join Exclude @a @e[type=Villager]
/execute @e[r=8,team=!Exclude,c=-1] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
```

Example using 1.9's "tags" feature:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add Exclude
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Villager] add Exclude
/execute @e[r=8,tag=!Exclude,c=-1] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
```